# Swift binary operator can not be applied into formatted function

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, double, currency-formatting

I am trying to add sum of the to values and converts to currency with hard coded string using formatted function. but I am having following errors.

**Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'String'**

I have tried formatted function with passing currency signal values and working fine but when I tried to use + operator to add two values I got above error .

Here is the line that rise the error ..

```
if isOn2 {
Text("\(order.productTotal + fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))")
        .bold()
       }
```

```
Here is the code ..

struct OrderView: View {
@State private var isOn1 = false
@State private var isOn2 = false

    var body: some View {

                 HStack {
                      Text("Grand total is :")
                            .bold()
                        Spacer()
                        if isOn2 {
                            Text("\(order.productTotal + fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))")
                                .bold()
                        } else {
                            Text("\(order.productTotal.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))")
                                .bold()
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(5)
}
```

Here is the screenshot..

[image]

Comment: try  `Text("\(order.productTotal)" + fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))
                                .bold()`

Comment: Sorry the purpose of using + operator is to add order.productTotal + fee

Comment: as the error said you cannot use + between two different types. You can only use + for same types (String + String), and (Int + Int),  (Double + Double) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add order.productTotal to fee and display the sum as a formatted string, use

```
Text("\((order.productTotal + fee).formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))")
    .bold()
```

(Add the two values together, and then format the sum as currency.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `order.productTotal` into a string, using `\()` and also convert the result of `fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP"))` into a string.

Change:

```
Text("\(order.productTotal + fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))")
```

to:

```
Text("\(order.productTotal) \(fee.formatted(.currency(code: "GBP")))")
```

Comment: Sorry the purpose of using + operator is to add order.productTotal + fee but with the changes it not adding total order.productTotal + fee

Comment: @Nus - ah... see Duncan's answer. Also, take a moment to review [ask] so it's clear what you are asking to begin with :)